# React Native Metro Keeps Refreshing then crashes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I am running my react-native application on ios enviroment. The app builds correctly and it gets launched and the app runs correctly for a few seconds but then it keeps refreshing by itself and the metro bundler crashes.

For some reason it keeps refreshing the app and suddenly the metro bundler server stops and the app stops running.

The error I am getting is not very informative and i dont understand the problem.

I am running xcode version 13.2.1 and here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "ProjectDilmune",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.23",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-header-scroll-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-styled-components": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the Error:

[image]